# Address-of operator with and without parentheses

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I came across a kernel patch which added a line `func(&(a->b))` when there was already `func(&a->b)`. Is there any difference between `&a->b` and `&(a->b)`?

Please explain.

Comment: Using parentheses just makes it clearer what you mean in this case.

Comment: @TylerSebastian No, the two expressions are equivalent. `->` has a higher precedence than `&`.

Comment: @PCLuddite yeah I remember right after I posted my comment and subsequently removed it.

Comment: `->` binds tighter than`&`. Parentheses are thus not needed, though macros should use an excessive amount of parentheses.

Comment: Not, because `->` operator has higher precedence than `&`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference, this is only for readability. the `->` has a higher precedence than the `&` reference operator. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

To further this proof, have a look at the dissasembly of these lines:

**Some short code**

```
struct A {
   int b;
};

int main() {
   struct A *a; 
   int *c;

   c = &a->b; // Disassemble these lines. 
   c = &(a->b);

   return 1;
}
```

The dissasembly of both lines equates to the following:

```
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
```

Try the code in [here](https://assembly.ynh.io/) to see for yourself.

Comment: You don't really need proof, it's absolutely clear in black and white in precedence rules :)

Comment: @teppic I know, i just like using that tool!

Answer (score 0):

No. `->foo` (for any value of `foo`) is a postfix operator and has higher precedence than `&` (a prefix operator).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.  The `->` component selection operator has higher precedence than the unary `&` operator, so the expression `&a->b` is parsed as `&(a->b)`, and the result is the address of the member `b` in the instance pointed to by `a`.